# Vite\rollup ignoring chunk ids

Tags: javascript, vite, rollup, chunks

I have my `manualChunks` method returning different values, say `a`, `b`, `c`.

The issues:

- Outputted files are not by the chunk name (`a`, `b`, `c`). chunkFileNames is also ignored when set
- Outputted files are separate entries, despite returning only `a`, `b`, `c`. Often files are by themselves, again ignoring `manualChunks` return value.

Comment: Is manualChunks something built into vite? if not share the code

Comment: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks

Comment: Can you add your `vite.config.js` file in the question description?

Comment: It's really not that compliated:

manualChunks: function(id){
if(some condition) return 'a';
if(another condition) return 'b';
return 'c';
}